# Pi-bond angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

I quantum chemistry literatute one can find a statement about projection of the angular momentum on internuclear axis:

> The angular momentum vector for rotation about the bond will lie along
>   the bond axis. This vector represents the component of the total
>   angular momentum vector along the internuclear axis. As in the atomic
>   case, quantum mechanics restricts the values of the component of the
>   total angular momentum vector along a given axis to integral multiples
>   of (h/2p). The quantum number in this case is denoted by the Greek
>   letter $\lambda$. It is analogous to the quantum number m in the
>   atomic case. The possible values for $\lambda$ are $0,1,2,3,\ldots$
>   The molecular orbitals are labelled according to the values of the
>   quantum number $\lambda$. When $\lambda = 0$, they are called $\sigma$ orbitals; when $\lambda = 1$, $\pi$ orbitals, etc. This is analogous to the
>   labelling of the atomic orbitals as $s, p, d, \ldots$ , as determined by
>   their $\ell$ value.

But I can't find any sources for the proof or strict mathematical treatment of this statement.

For example, lets consider $\pi$ bond which is created by two $p_z$ atomic orbitals:
[image]

As we know for $p$ orbitals, it describe the state with angular momentum $l=1$, and $m_z = 0$ ($z$ axis perpendicular to the plane in picture) and the direction along internuclear axis undefined for individual $p_z$ orbitals. How can one show for simplest model MO - LCAO $\pi = c_1 p_{z_1}  +c_2 p_{z_2}$, the projection of the angular momentum on internuclear axis should be $1$?

Answer (score 3):

Let the molecular axis be the $z$ axis, A and B the two atoms forming the bond. The $2p_z$ AO has atomic quantum number $m_l = 0$ and so has $L_z =0$. The MOs formed from
$2p_z$ AOs are therefore $\sigma$ MOs, bonding and antibonding and not the $\pi$. Instead the $p_x$ AO is a linear combination of $m =+ 1$ and $m = -1$ AOs and has $|m| =1$.

$2p_x \equiv \frac{(2p_1 + 2p_{-1}) } {\sqrt 2}$

$2p_y \equiv \frac{(2p_1 - 2p_{-1}) } {i\sqrt 2}$

Therefore the MOs made from the $2p_x$ and $2p_y$ AOs have $|m| = 1$  and are $\pi$ MOs.

Comment: I think the statement $|m| = 1 $ needs some justification.